# Font object - Using Windows Raster Fonts

Tags: java, fonts, swt

I am trying to make an SWT CMD imitation (for windows). I have found that CMD uses the font 'Raster Fonts' 8x12. I have the following code:

```
text.setFont(new Font(display, "[how do I use raster fonts?]", [what size?], SWT.NORMAL));
```

How can I use the windows 8x12 raster fonts?

**---DOES NOT WORK---**

The following does not work (yes I know the size is not right):

```
text.setFont(new Font(display, "Raster Fonts", 15, SWT.NORMAL));
```

*** EDIT ***
I am trying to use the font called 'Raster Fonts 8x12'. I need to find a way to use this system *raster font*, the same exact one used by windows command prompt, in my SWT textbox. This font is not a TTF.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this:

```
Display display = new Display();
FontData fontData = new public FontData(String name, int height, int style); 
// Try the name as Raster or find the correct value.
Font newFont = new Font(display, fontData);
text.setFont(newFont);
```

At the end please don't forget to

```
newFont.dispose();
```

In font data you need to set the font type that you want...

Comment: How does this let me use the windows System Raster Font 8x12? It does not work(tried it)

Comment: The problem is that I ***don't*** know the font name.

Comment: I think it is called Bitmap fonts... You might want to debug and see

Comment: Its called that ... I didn't say try it ... if i were to try i would have tried only bitmap ... and not bitmaps fonts...